# Find SQLite Column Names in Empty Table

Tags: database, sqlite, schema

For kicks I'm writing a "schema documentation" tool that generates a description of the tables and relationships in a database.  I'm currently shimming it to work with SQLite.

I've managed to extract the names of all the tables in a SQLite database via a query on the `sqlite_master` table.  For each table name, I then fire off a simple

```
select * from <table name>
```

query, then use the `sqlite3_column_count()` and `sqlite3_column_name()` APIs to collect the  column names, which I further feed to `sqlite3_table_column_metadata()` to get additional info.  Simple enough, right?

The problem is that it only works for tables that are not empty.  That is, the `sqlite_column_*()` APIs are only valid if `sqlite_step()` has returned `SQLITE_ROW`, which is not the case for empty tables.

So the question is, how can I discover column names for empty tables?  Or, more generally, is there a better way to get this type of schema info in SQLite?

I feel like there must be another hidden `sqlite_xxx` table lurking somewhere containing this info, but so far have not been able to find it.

Comment: Thanks to all.  I mistakenly thought the PRAGMA interface was only for the `sqlite3` command line client.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
sqlite> .header on
sqlite> .mode column
sqlite> create table ABC(A TEXT, B VARCHAR);
sqlite> pragma table_info(ABC);
cid         name        type        notnull     dflt_value  pk
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0           A           TEXT        0                       0
1           B           VARCHAR     0                       0
```

Comment: Looks like that works on the command line--how can I achieve the same effect programatically?

Comment: Thanks--this worked like a charm & is much simpler than what I was doing.  Cheers!

Comment: @Drew Hall This works also as a query executed programatically, not only from command line.

Answer (score 10):

Execute the query:

```
PRAGMA table_info( your_table_name );
```

[Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html)

Answer (score 5):

`PRAGMA table_info( your_table_name );` doesn't work in HTML5 SQLite.

Here is a small HTML5 SQLite JavaScript Snippet which gets the column names from your_table_name even if its empty. Hope its helpful.

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT name, sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table" AND name = "your_table_name";', [], function (tx, results) {
  var columnParts = results.rows.item(0).sql.replace(/^[^\(]+\(([^\)]+)\)/g, '$1').split(',');
  var columnNames = [];
  for(i in columnParts) {
    if(typeof columnParts[i] === 'string')
      columnNames.push(columnParts[i].split(" ")[0]);
  }
  console.log(columnNames);
  ///// Your code which uses the columnNames;
});
```

Comment: It looks like if your table has more than one column, columns 2 - n don't get processed because of leading whitespace.  This can be fixed by calling the `trim()` function on the string (or implementing it yourself for browsers that don't yet support `trim()`).

Calling the above function on a table (Person) with an ID and Name field returns `["id", ""]`.

Comment: This is a major SQL "injection" risk.

Answer (score 4):

Execute this query

```
select * from (select "") left join my_table_to_test b on -1 = b.rowid;
```

You can try it at [online sqlite engine](http://wdbengine.sourceforge.net)

Comment: this way is the best! If you dont know the name of the `rowid` column I suggest using: `SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT 1) LEFT JOIN table AS t
LIMIT 1`

Comment: The suggestion by @conca led me to the solution I needed, which was to union the normal query with the "backup query for empty tables".  `SELECT * from 'table' UNION SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT 1) LEFT JOIN 'table' AS t;"` This allows a single query to work whether the table has data or not, and I can access the column names.  Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 3):

The `PRAGMA` statement suggested by @pragmanatu works fine through any programmatic interface, too.  Alternatively, the `sql` column of `sqlite_master` has the `SQL` statement `CREATE TABLE &c &c` that describes the table (but, you'd have to parse that, so I think `PRAGMA table_info` is more... pragmatic;-).

Answer (score 0):

If you are suing SQLite 3.8.3 or later (supports the WITH clause), this recursive query should work for basic tables. On CTAS, YMMV.

```
WITH
    Recordify(tbl_name, Ordinal, Clause, Sql)
AS
    (
     SELECT
        tbl_name,
        0,

        '',
        Sql
     FROM
        (
         SELECT
            tbl_name,
            substr
            (
             Sql,
             instr(Sql, '(') + 1,
             length(Sql) - instr(Sql, '(') - 1
            ) || ',' Sql
         FROM
            sqlite_master
         WHERE
            type = 'table'
        )
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
        tbl_name,
        Ordinal + 1,
        trim(substr(Sql, 1, instr(Sql, ',') - 1)),
        substr(Sql, instr(Sql, ',') + 1)
     FROM
        Recordify
     WHERE
        Sql > ''
       AND  lower(trim(Sql)) NOT LIKE 'check%'
       AND  lower(trim(Sql)) NOT LIKE 'unique%'
       AND  lower(trim(Sql)) NOT LIKE 'primary%'
       AND  lower(trim(Sql)) NOT LIKE 'foreign%'
       AND  lower(trim(Sql)) NOT LIKE 'constraint%'
    ),
    -- Added to make querying a subset easier.
    Listing(tbl_name, Ordinal, Name, Constraints)
AS
    (
     SELECT
        tbl_name,
        Ordinal,
        substr(Clause, 1, instr(Clause, ' ') - 1),
        trim(substr(Clause, instr(Clause, ' ') + 1))
     FROM
        Recordify
     WHERE
        Ordinal > 0
    )
SELECT
    tbl_name,
    Ordinal,
    Name,
    Constraints
FROM
    Listing
ORDER BY
    tbl_name,
    lower(Name);
```