# Get column names in sqlite3

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I would like to print my sql table contents and for that reason, I would like to retrieve the column name from the table. One solution I came across was :

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE tbl_name = 'table_name' AND type = 'table'
```

But looks like I will have to parse the results.

Another suggestion was to use:

```
PRAGMA table_info(table_name);
```

but the below sqlite page suggests not to use this : 
http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_full_column_names

Does there exists any way to achieve this. Also what would be the syntax to use

```
PRAGMA table_info(table_name);
```

Above solutions have been taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947215/how-to-get-a-list-of-column-names-on-sqlite3-iphone)

Comment: I asked a similar question a while ago.  See the answers there:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928865/find-sqlite-column-names-in-empty-table

Answer (score 9):

Since your question is tagged `c` I assume you have access to the SQLite C API. If you create a prepared statement with one of the [prepare_v2 functions](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) that selects from the table you want you can use [sqlite3_column_name](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_name.html) to get the name of each column.

Comment: What if you don't have any records in that table?

Comment: I believe the column names are still available even if there are no results.

Answer (score 4):

You can safely use [`PRAGMA table_info(table-name);`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) since it's *not* deprecated in any way (yours post links to another pragma).

Answer (score 1):

```
int sqlite3_get_table(
    sqlite3 *db,          /* An open database */
    const char *zSql,     /* SQL to be evaluated */
    char ***pazResult,    /* Results of the query */
    int *pnRow,           /* Number of result rows written here */
    int *pnColumn,        /* Number of result columns written here */
    char **pzErrmsg       /* Error msg written here */
    );
```

If you are using c/c++, you can use the function sqlite3_get_table(db, query, result, nrow, ncol, errmsg);

Make the query as select * from table;

And the first few results result[0], result[1]...... will have the column names.

Comment: That function is [deprecated](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/free_table.html): "This is a legacy interface that is preserved for backwards compatibility. Use of this interface is not recommended."

Answer (score 0):

This setting will toggle showing column names as part of the return for select statements:

```
.headers on
```