# Find SQLite Column Names in Empty Table/View in an attached database

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

The same thing as [Find SQLite Column Names in Empty Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928865/find-sqlite-column-names-in-empty-table) with the exception that I have a view that is part of an attached database. Because the database is attached the `PRAGMA table_info( your_table_name );` solution doesnt work. Furthermore, trying to parse the query string is also ridiculous because it is a view query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PRAGMA AttachedDbName.table_info(your_table_name)`

Another technique: prepare a statement of the form `select * from your_table_name;`, then use `sqlite3_column_count`, `sqlite3_column_name` et al. You don't need to actually run the statement, just prepare it.