# Get the column names and values in SQLite for Windows Runtime apps

Tags: windows, sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, sqlite-net

How to get column names and its values in SQLite for windows runtime apps (Windows 8.1 apps).

In Android it can be done easily like the following code snippet:

```
...
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from  Student");
String[] columnNames = cursor.getColumnNames();
...
```

I am using `Sqlite-net` library for my windows project. I'm following this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826602/Using-SQLite-as-local-database-with-Universal-Apps).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a list of column names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685206/how-to-get-a-list-of-column-names) and [Find SQLite Column Names in Empty Table](http://stackoverflow.com/q/928865/1889329).

Comment: Also relevant: [PRAGMA table_info](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info).

Comment: Show the function you're actually using to execute the query.

Comment: Hi CL, I'm using `await conn.ExecuteAsync(query);` from `conn= new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);`

Comment: How can this be duplicate ? He is asking to get both the column names and the values per column. Please answer the question. @everyone

Comment: @BiswasKhayargoli-ITH: The OP already knows how to get the values. The query is in the question. They have difficulty querying the column names. And that is a duplicate of the question I linked to.